# Touchpad scrolling not working

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, scrolling

I have a Dell 5720 (Inspiron 17R), with a distro based up on Ubuntu 12.04.

My scrolling doesn't work. When I set it to scroll with two fingers, the setting backs to disabled when I open the window again.

I've installed a program "synaptics" but nothing happens and I don't know how to set this up.

Also, the output of "xinput" is this (looks like my system sees my touchpad as a mouse):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MLK 2.4G Laser Mouse                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the "Unity Tweak Tool" from Ubuntu Software Center. There is an option where you can activate and deactivate horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

As user256422 said, install the "Unity Tweak Tool" from ubuntu software center. Open it and in the system section look for "scrolling". You can set it to use 2 fingers or edge, thats up to you. Tested it and worked on my laptop.